# Duplicate question of multiple User

Tags: support, duplicate-user

I see multiple user that asked same question with same property and same problem on Stack Overflow. unfortunately i don't have all link, but in 29 march this question asked more than 5 time and i see this question asked now again, i post 2 link of them.

[Very very Simple Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857663/very-very-simple-application#22857834)

[Unfortunately application has stopped android emulator genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737319/unfortunately-application-has-stopped-android-emulator-genymotion/22737675?noredirect=1#comment34655651_22737675)

as you see all code is same each other, i think its not possible that multiple user use one wrong code.

please check, Thank you so much.

Comment: Just my guess, they were following a tutorial article/book, and were stumped by new ADT feature which automatically create a `Fragment`. But anyway, they should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewT. Maybe you right but in witch tutorial you faced with `NPE`, and ten user use that,?

Comment: Well, if the tutorial was from an outdated book (long before ADT 22), and since the default layout is `fragment_main.xml`, I don't see why it might happen, considering ADT 22 was release on March. Edit: I found the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662546/findviewbyid-in-java-r-id-badd) which mentioned the [tutorial source](http://thenewboston.org/).

Comment: vaw, i think you right @AndrewT., thanks for your time